# libusb-1.0 debug informations

Tags: c, debugging, libusb-1.0

I’m wondering if libusb_set_debug() works. I can’t get any output from it.
I can turn on debug logging if I configure and build with --enable-debug-log.
Should I get about the same output as enable-debug-log if I set libusb_set_debug() to 3?
I don’t have the LIBUSB_DEBUG env variable set.
I assume I’m missing something simple.
Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

The libusb debugging options don't work as documented. How they actually work is like this:

If you configure with `--enable-debug-log` then, when compiling, you unconditionally activate all DEBUG, INFO, WARNING and ERROR messages for all contexts.

If you configure with `--disable-log` then, when compiling, you unconditionally deactivate all logging messages at all levels.

With debug-log disabled, and logging enabled (the default) then you can use libusb_set_debug to request INFO, WARNING and ERROR messages for particular contexts, but it is NOT possible to request DEBUG level messages, despite there being a logging level for it.

The author of libusb seems to consider this broken behaviour to be a feature, and does not plan to change it. See this:
http://libusb.6.n5.nabble.com/does-libusb-set-debug-work-td7638.html#a7641