# How to get Android USB API debug log

Tags: android, debugging, libusb

I have android app with implemented interaction over USB (with sources) and i'm facing some difficulties with implementing the same in native code using libusb. Is there any chanсe to get libusb invocations log for Android USB API?

Update: It seems that Android uses libusbhost not libusb

Comment: the only idea i have now is to recompile libusb (if Android uses it) with debug mode turned on and replace current files. But it looks hacky and can hurt the system somehow..

Comment: it seems that android does not use libusb behind the scene. there is no libusb.so in /system/lib folder..

Comment: Hope this help you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8480388/libusb-1-0-debug-informations

Looks like it's a WontFix bug

Comment: Thanks but this relates to libusb and not to android